# WP custom post title or label

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been trying to get my custom post title but so far no luck, I tried the reference as well couldn't make it to work.

```
function create_aop_post_types(){
$args = array(
    'label'              => 'News',
    'public'             => true,
    'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'news' ),
    'has_archive'        => true,
    'menu_position'      => null,
    'taxonomies'         => array('category', 'post_tag'),
    'supports'           => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments', 'custom-fields', 'revisions' )
);

register_post_type( 'news', $args );
```

Trying to output 'label' => 'News' in a href  and I tried the_title(); with permalink.

```
<div class="feedhead news clearfix"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></a></div>
        <div class="newscol-items">
            <?php
            //Instead do this using a WP Query and loop.
            $queryargs = array(
                'post_type'=>'news',
                'showposts'=>5
            );
            query_posts($queryargs);
            if (have_posts()){
                $count = 0;
                while (have_posts()) {
                    the_post();
                    $count++;
                    get_template_part('content','news');
                }
            } else {
                get_template_part('content','noposts');
            }
            wp_reset_query();
            ?>
        </div>
```

so far I'm only doing  but I'm sure there is a better way of doing it than what I've tried.

Comment: Are you using a custom page to display the results or a single/archive page?

If you are using a custom page you'll need to provide a custom query. You seem to have the definition working alright as you can create your new post type.

Answer (score 1):

This code is working for me and this will fetch current page post type label.

```
<?php $post_type = get_post_type_object( get_post_type( get_the_ID()) );
        echo $post_type->labels->singular_name ; ?>
```

Comment: This is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

For the title, the_permalink() and the_title() need to be inside the while loop. And then you won't need to use get_the_title() either. For the label, a custom field is better. See this page: http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

```
    <div class="newscol-items">
        <?php
        //Instead do this using a WP Query and loop.
        $queryargs = array(
            'post_type'=>'news',
            'showposts'=>5
        );
        query_posts($queryargs);
        if (have_posts()){
            $count = 0;
            while (have_posts()) { ?>
                <div class="feedhead news clearfix"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
                <?php the_post();
                $count++;
                get_template_part('content','news');
            }
        } else {
            get_template_part('content','noposts');
        }
        wp_reset_query();
        ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: I need to get the label name not the post title. 'label'              => 'News',

Comment: The get_post_type function should help; inside the loop, the post object has a post_type variable as well. If this does not return the label then custom fields is your best option

Answer (score -1):

Use [advanced custom fields](http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/85-best-practices-dynamic-content/) then create a field called `mycustom_title`, then do

```
<?php the_field("[mycustom_title]"); ?>
```